# Error installing to PostClassLoader: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Cannot process metadata

Tags: deployment, jboss5.x, classnotfound

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide:

I'm developing an EJB 3 application on JBoss 5.0.1 GA.  The application I'm deploying has worked for a couple of years with no problems.  However recently I've been upgrading some functionality, and I've had to update one of the libraries that my main EJB module (MyEJB.jar) uses.  It actually comes from a third party, so I don't have full control over the library, we'll call it foo.jar.  So MyEJB.jar uses foo.jar as a library, and has done so successfully for a while now.  The third party updated that foo.jar, and now when I deploy, JBoss reports this error:  **Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfsfile:/opt/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/MyEJB.jar/ state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Cannot process metadata**

Below this error in the stack track I see the following that appears to  be the root cause of the problem:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Foo from BaseClassLoader@68b9ec2b{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@64030c4{name=vfsfile:/opt/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/MyEJBjar/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@df1cbf6{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@4383f74d} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@16
14911248[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4o01b-7nn4aj-go4u51sb-1-go4u5c2j-24 real=vfsmemory://5c4o01b-7nn4aj-go4u51sb-1-go4u5c2j-24], FileHandler@1915014350[path=MyEJBjar
context=file:/opt/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/opt/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/MyEJBjar/], DelegatingHandler@1308762861[path=G
 org.snmp4j.smi, net.sf.json.regexp, package cache, org.snmp4j.security, net.sf.json, META-INF, net.sf.json.groovy, com.mycompany.util.clipgeneration] NON_EMPTY}}
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:448)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.jboss.deployment.OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processJBossClientMetaData(OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:115)
        at org.jboss.deployment.OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processMetaData(OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:82)
        at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:177)
        ... 32 more

**What could have been done to Foo that would cause JBoss not to find it when it loads?  The permissions and location are the same, and so is the owner (running on Linux RedHat 5.4)?**

**How can I fix the Cannot process metadata problem?**

Again thank you!

Cheers,